# Getting Battery Level while in background mode

Tags: ios, ios6

We want to build an app that will monitor battery of every device we own as a background activity, and upload that information every hour to the server. This way we'll be able to know when a device needs to be recharged every so much time.

I'm not sure how I can get this information while the app is in the background. I dont seem to get a notification if its not active. Is this possible at all? Here's my code if it helps in any way.

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:YES];
// Request to be notified when battery charge or state changes
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(batteryStatus) name:UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChangeNotification object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(batteryStatus) name:UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];

- (void)batteryStatus
{
    NSArray *batteryStatus = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                          @"Battery status is unknown.",
                          @"Battery is in use (discharging).",
                          @"Battery is charging.",
                          @"Battery is fully charged.", nil];

//    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] == UIApplicationStateBackground)
//        [self notifyServer];
// do something. this is never called when in background.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] batteryState] == UIDeviceBatteryStateUnknown)
    {
        [textViewStatus setText:[batteryStatus objectAtIndex:0]];
        NSLog(@"%@", [batteryStatus objectAtIndex:0]);
    }
    else
    {
        NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                     @"Battery charge level: %0.2f%%\n%@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] batteryLevel] * 100,
                     [batteryStatus objectAtIndex:[[UIDevice currentDevice] batteryState]] ];

        [textViewStatus setText:msg];  
        NSLog(@"%@", msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this for jailbroken or nonjailbroken?

Comment: Have you enabled running in the background? See `UIBackgroundModes`; you might try `location` or `voip`.

Comment: non jailbroken. I'll try setting one of the UIBackgroundMode, but if it does work, it will be more of a hack than anything else. Posting results later.

Comment: definitely not working with any of those background modes.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to tell you that such background service is not allowed, hence not possible on a non jailbroken iOS device.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just doing this for your own devices and are not intending to put the app on the app store you could investigate setting the `voip` background mode and then keep registering background tasks. As far as I know Apps that use the `voip` or `audio` background mode are allowed to do pretty much anything they want in the background and are not terminated after 10 minutes.

Further documentation can be found here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html